# Html, Css - On hover style not working for submit form input type

Tags: html, css

This is my html form inside a card html. This form appears after an `onlick` function which works fine. But the submit button of the below form doesn't show hover effect.

```
<!-- Update details form here -->
                    <div class="UpdateForm-section">
                        <form action="/add_address" method="post">
                            <label>Car Name</label>
                            <input type="text" value="" name="ev_name" placeholder="Model name"><br>
                            <label>Manufacturer</label>
                            <input type="text" value="" name="ev_manufacturer" placeholder="Brand name"><br>
                            <label>Year</label>
                            <input type="number" value="" name="ev_year" placeholder="YYYY"><br>
                            <label>Battery size</label>
                            <input type="number" value="" step="any" name="ev_battery" placeholder="Capacity in Kwh"><br>
                            <label>Range</label>
                            <input type="number" value="" name="ev_range" placeholder="Range in Km"><br>
                            <label>Cost</label>
                            <input type="number" value="" name="ev_cost" placeholder="Price in €"><br>
                            <label>Power</label>
                            <input type="number" value="" name="ev_power" placeholder="Power in Kw"><br>
                            <br>
                            <input type="submit" id="update_submit" value="Update details" name="submit_button"/>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

And my css file is:

```
#update_submit {
  width: auto;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin: 4px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#update_submit : hover {
  background-color: #ab1313;
}
```

I don't why my hover effect isn't visible. Am I doing anything wrong? Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but in your `#update_submit` i think is not allowed to let empty spaces between `ID` and the hover state. Try to write it all together.

Comment: I made a silly mistake. Thanks @ToniBordoy for pointing it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding space in `#update_submit : hover` remove spaces and write like this

```
#update_submit:hover
```

Answer (score 2):

The colon symbol must be right next to both

```
#update_submit:hover {
    background-color: #ab1313;
}
```